# Angular unit tests fail, but not locally

Tags: angular, unit-testing, travis-ci

After upgrading to Angular version 11, unit tests now fail on Travis CI. Locally they do succeed (even after clean install with the same node, nvm and npm versions).

The error for all unit tests is the same -

```
Failed: fn.bind is not a function
    TypeError: fn.bind is not a function
        at newTrustedFunctionForJIT (node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:6845:1)
        at JitEvaluator.evaluateCode (node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:6909:1)
        at JitEvaluator.evaluateStatements (node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:6883:1)
```

Based on the error message, I would assume that the issue might be related to ngcc? Anyone had similar issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Today I had the same problem. It involved testing with ChromeHeadless.

I had old version of Chrome Headless 83.0.4103.97 installed in docker image. After updating it to latest version 88.0.4324.96 it started to work.

Comment: Thanks! That resolved the issue. I did add the following to the travis.yml file, if anyone else needs answer -


addons:
  chrome: stable

Comment: Dumb question but where do i update this Locally?

Answer (score 4):

Additional [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/40507) is the corresponding angular github issue.

Using **Chrome >= 87** should [fix](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/40507#issuecomment-764687343) the issue.